# How do V8 "internal" calls work, such as valueOf?

Tags: chromium, v8

I can't find in the V8 code a call to the valueOf method during type casting in this example:

```js
let foo = {
  valueOf: () => 0
};
foo + 1; // 1
```

I tried debugging the code and printing the stack trace via `base::debug::StackTrace().Print()` in the LookupIterator constructor here [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main:v8/src/objects/lookup-inl.h;drc=d04c3f5aa44a179ef0c65faae5d94a9451e43f5a;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=67?q=LookupIterator&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc:v8%2Fsrc%2F), but alas, I did not understand exactly where the valueOf call comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fairly long chain to trace through "builtins" implemented in various techniques. It starts at [`Generate_AddWithFeedback`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/ic/binary-op-assembler.h;l=19) and ends in [`builtin OrdinaryToPrimitive_Number_Inline`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main:v8/src/builtins/conversion.tq;l=240) which passes `ValueOfStringConstant()` as a parameter to `macro TryToPrimitiveMethod` defined right above it.

(That's for the interpreter; other execution tiers will use other code paths. V8 is complex.)

> How do V8 "internal" calls work, such as valueOf?

As far as the call itself is concerned, it works just like any other call. From the rest of your question, it seemed that what you really wanted to know was where that call is happening.

Comment: Yes, thank you! You're right, I was wondering about the call chain. What's the best way to trace it? Im very interested in how it all works

Comment: @mashau I just traced in codesearch; the challenge there is that linking between Torque builtins (`*.tq` files) and CodeStubAssembler builtins/functions doesn't work, so you have to rely on full-text search to find the next definition whenever you need to cross that boundary.