# How torque's "extern transitioning macro" is implemented in CodeStubAssembler

Tags: chromium, v8

My question is a kind of sequel to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76136373/how-do-v8-internal-calls-work-such-as-valueof). There @jmrk explained to me where the `valueOf()` method is called when converting an object to a number.
The `TryToPrimitiveMethod` code has a [GetProperty call](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main:v8/src/builtins/conversion.tq;l=220), which is declared [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main:v8/src/builtins/base.tq;drc=76be2f9f117654f3fe4faa477b0445114fccedda;l=697) as `extern transitioning macro GetProperty(...)`.

The [Torque user manual](https://v8.dev/docs/torque) says that if a macro is marked as `extern`, "the implementation must be provided as hand-written CSA code in a CodeStubAssembler class".
I found an implementation of this method [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/codegen/code-stub-assembler.h;l=3285) and tried first to output a stack trace and then a plain string in `std::cout`. But I didn't get any results at all at runtime. Why does this happen and is it possible to get any output at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost found the right implementation: Torque's `JSAny` maps to the CodeStubAssembler's `TNode<Object>`, so the `GetProperty` overload you're looking for is the other one, in line 3290:

```
  TNode<Object> GetProperty(TNode<Context> context, TNode<Object> receiver,
                            TNode<Object> name) {
    return CallBuiltin(Builtin::kGetProperty, context, receiver, name);
  }
```

When inserting any printing code there (or setting a breakpoint, for that matter), you won't see any output at runtime because all of that code (both Torque and CSA) only runs during the V8 build process. It's not even included in the final binaries. It's used to generate builtins; these builtins are in the final binaries.

For `printf`-style debugging, there are a few [`Print`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/codegen/code-stub-assembler.h;l=3952) functions in CSA, which emit the equivalent of `printf` calls into the generated builtins.